# RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Double (LSTM classifier)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, lstm

I'm training my LSTM classifier.

```
epoch_num = 30

train_log = []
test_log = []
set_seed(111)
for epoch in range(1, epoch_num+1):

running_loss = 0    
train_loss = []
lstm_classifier.train()
for (inputs, labels) in tqdm(train_loader, desc='Training epoch ' + str(epoch), leave=False):        
    inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)        
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = lstm_classifier(inputs)   
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()                
    optimizer.step()        
    train_loss.append(loss.item())
train_log.append(np.mean(train_loss))

running_loss = 0
test_loss = []
lstm_classifier.eval()
with torch.no_grad():                
    for (inputs, labels) in tqdm(test_loader, desc='Test', leave=False):         
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)        
        outputs = lstm_classifier(inputs)                       
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)            
        test_loss.append(loss.item())
test_log.append(np.mean(test_loss))    
plt.plot(range(1, epoch+1), train_log, color='C0')
plt.plot(range(1, epoch+1), test_log, color='C1')
display.clear_output(wait=True)
display.display(plt.gcf())
```

### error is:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

```
     23         print((labels.dtype))
     24         print(outputs[:,0].dtype)
---> 25         loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
     26         loss.backward()
     27         optimizer.step()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2822     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2823         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2824     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2825 
   2826
```

RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Double

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

> RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Double

The error at line `loss = criterion(outputs, labels)` is quite clear in that it requites your datatype to be float rather than double, but it doesn't explicitly say whether `outputs` or `label` is creating this.

My guess is its because of labels. Try converting it to float by doing `labels.float()`

Comment: Odd. Can you provide samples of outputs and labels to replicate this error?